# JS window.location not working from .js file

Tags: javascript, redirect, window.location

I have the following issue. 
I have this javsacript code inside login.js file:

```
login (userField, passField)
{
    // debugger;
    var json = this.loginLogic(document.getElementById(userField).value, document.getElementById(passField).value);
    setCookie("idSesion", json.usuario.idSesion);
    if (json.usuario.rol=="administrador") {
        window.location.href = 'perfilAdministrador.html';
    }
    else if (json.usuario.rol=="alumno") {
        window.location.href = '../html/perfilAlumno.html';
    }
    else if (json.usuario.rol=="profesor") {
        window.location.href = '../html/perfilProfesor.html';
    }
    else {
        console.log("Error");
    }
};
```

I have an html button that executes an onclick that calls this login method (i call it method because its inside a javascript class named class `LoginControllerLocal{}`)
This is the html code:

```
   <button type="submit" onclick="myfunction()">Ingresar</button>
  <script>
     function myfunction() {
       var lc = new LoginControllerLocal;  
      lc.login("username", "password");
      }
 </script>
```

The issue is the following. I have used debugger to see if the code is executed inside the `login.js` file. It is, and it reaches the point were it executes the redirection to `window.location.href = 'perfilAdministrador.html';`
However, it is not redirected. Instead i get stuck in login.html. Function is not returning any error or anything.
What is weird is that if i run the redirect the following way, it works:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  window.location = 'perfilAdministrador.html';
});
```

The thing is, i can't just execute the redirect on page load because i need to validate the login first. Before asking why am i redirecting with javascript and not using php, this is a school assignment and has to work entirely with javascript.
Any idea why this issue is happening? appreaciate all the help i can get :)

Comment: Well, is it logging "error" ?

Comment: The code is odd, where have you defined `login` function? Probably a typo in the post ... Anyway, you've a pending server call after you've clicked on the submit button, and that blocks the changes to `location` object. Pass the event object to `myfunction`, and prevent the default action, that way the location blocking is not set. Or just use a button of a type of button instead of a type of submit.

Comment: @Teemu holy shit man! that worked!! spent hours on this issue, stayed up all night, and it was as easy as changing the type of the button. Never in my life have i felt this stupid. Appreaciate it, thanks for your help!!!